# gradle task build already exists issue

Tags: gradle

I am getting the error

```
Cannot add task ':webserver:build' as a task with that name already exists.
```

The weird thing is my `hello` task is fine but my `build` task is not AND YES, I am trying to override the Java plugin's build task.

Master `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'

   task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
   task build << { task -> println "I'm building now" }
}

subprojects {

    hello << {println "- I depend on stserver"}

    build << { println "source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs" }
}
```

My child webserver `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets.main{
  java.srcDirs = ['app']
}

build << { println "source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs" }

hello << {println "- Do something specific xxxx"}
```

What is the deal here, is overriding `build` special or something? Overriding my own `hello` task worked fine and I thought overriding `build` would be just as simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the deal here, overriding build is special or something. Overriding my own hello task worked fine and I thought overriding build would be just as simple?

The reason the behaviour *seems* different is because `build` task already exists and `hello` does not (and not because `build` is special).

In gradle you cannot do this:

```
task hello << { print "hello" }
task hello << { print "hello again" }
```

This will fail with the familiar error: `"Cannot add task ':hello' as a task with that name already exists."`.

Since `build` task already exists, it's illegal to have a second `task build << { ... }`. However, it will work for `hello` task, because it does not exist, and therefore `task hello << { ... }` is legal, as it's the first declaration of `hello` task.

If you replace your `task build << { ... }` with `build << { ... }`, which just adds more behaviour to an *existing* task, it will "compile" fine.

Comment: heh, I had tried that and it didn't work but finally fonud out there was another task build in yet another gradle file that I had missed...my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 11):

You aren't overriding the `hello` task, you are just adding more task actions. You can override a task with `task foo(overwrite: true)`. I haven't come across a good reason to override the `build` task; there are probably better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: probably but for now, I just need to get it done...as I understand it more, I will certainly need to revisit some stuff.

Comment: @Peter Thanks really helped. Overwirte is really useful when we are dealing with multiple gradle script files. For Instance: Let's assume A.gradle has some task and it is used in (apply from:'A.gradle') B.gradle and C.gradle. Now there is an another gradle file say D.gradle needs both B and C features. We will face task duplication for all the tasks defined in A when we import it. And I feel declaring overwrite true for the tasks defined in A.gradle would be right think to do. Or there should be some other workaround exists which I am unaware of .